# How to write a Makefile rule to download a file only if it is missing?

Tags: code-generation, makefile

I'm trying to write a Makefile which should download some sources if and only if they are missing.

Something like:

```
hello: hello.c
    gcc -o hello hello.c

hello.c:
    wget -O hello.c http://example.org/hello.c
```

But of course this causes `hello.c` to be downloaded every time make command is run. I would like `hello.c` to be downloaded by this Makefile only if it is missing. Is this possible with GNU make and how to do this if it is?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My guess is that wget doesn't update the timestamp on hello.c, but retains the remote timestamp. This causes `make` to believe that hello.c is old and attempts to download it again. Try

```
hello.c:
        wget ...
        touch $@
```

EDIT: The -N option to wget will prevent wget from downloading anything unless the remote file is newer (but it'll still check the timestamp of the remote file, of course.)

Comment: Sorry for being blunt, but a vague question like that is going to get a bunch of guesses.

Comment: **The answer is wrong** because, target `hello.c: ` is **not** remade (and the file's not downloaded) if file named "hello.c" already exists--regardless of its timestamp.  The second reason is that with -O option the file's timestamp *always* coincides with download time.

Comment: But since the question was wrong, I'm not surprised that the wrong answer occurred to be correct one. >_<

Comment: Pavel, wget 1.15 would preserve the timestamp even with the `-O` option. You are still correct that make would not look at the timestamp (there is no other timestamp for make to compare).

Answer (score 7):

The `Makefile` you wrote downloads `hello.c` only if it's missing. Perhaps you are doing something else wrong? See for example:

```
hello: hello.c
        gcc -o hello hello.c

hello.c:
        echo 'int main() {}' > hello.c
```

And:

```
% make
echo 'int main() {}' > hello.c
gcc -o hello hello.c
% rm hello
% make
gcc -o hello hello.c
% rm hello*
% make
echo 'int main() {}' > hello.c
gcc -o hello hello.c
```

(the `echo` command was not executed the second time)

Comment: Silly me, forgot to run this simple test. It appeared that wget was messing with file dates... Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't break the functionality.

Answer (score 7):

Since the Makefile should be working as you want, you need to check a few unlikely cases:

1) Check that you don't have any `.PHONY` rules mentioning the source file.

2) Check that the source target name matches the file path you are downloading.

You could also try running `make -d` to see why make thinks it needs to 're-build' the source file.

Comment: Also make sure that `wget` doesn't fail and that the name after `-O` matches the target. Better yet, use `$@` instead of `hello.c` in the `wget` command.

Answer (score 2):

If the prerequisite for `hello.c` has changed or is empty and Make continues to download the file when it exists, then one option to prevent Make from re-downloading the file is to use a flag in the body of the target to detect if the file exists:

```
hello.c:
    test -f $@ || wget -O hello.c http://example.org/hello.c
```

The `test` command will return `true` if the `hello.c` file exists, otherwise it will return `false` and the `wget` command will run.